# C++ filereader giving error

Tags: c++

I got code for a filereader for C++ from a website but I can't seem to get it to work for me, is there something wrong with the code  or should I just use something else to read text form a textfile?

The Error I get is:

E:\IT-C++\snake.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
E:\IT-C++\snake.cpp|11|error: could not convert 'infile.std::basic_ios<_CharT, _Traits>::eof [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits]' to 'bool'|
E:\IT-C++\snake.cpp|11|error: in argument to unary !|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
        string STRING;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open ("names.txt");
        while(!infile.eof) // To get you all the lines.
        {
            getline(infile,STRING); // Saves the line in STRING.
            cout<<STRING; // Prints our STRING.
        }
    infile.close();

}
```

Comment: Whatever website you found that on, stay away from it.  Checking `eof()` before the read is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard line-by-line file reading idiom goes like this:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream infile("names.txt");

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
  std::cout << "We read: " << line << std::endl;
}
```

No need to close the file explicitly, as that's done automatically when `infile` goes out of scope. Note that we never say `eof`, since that doesn't do what you want!

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!infile.eof() )
              // ^^  missed. It's a member function of input output stream
```

You should start reading depending on the success of opening the file i.e., return value of member function  [`ifstream::is_open()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/is_open/).

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
while (getline(infile,STRING)) { // Saves the line in STRING.
    cout<<STRING; // Prints our STRING.
}
```

The error flags such as `eof` aren't set until after you've tried and failed to read past the end.  The code as designed (even if the missing parentheses in `infile.eof()` are added) will process garbage on the final iteration when `getline` fails.  So you have to test the stream status after `getline` runs, as I show here.

Answer (score 0):

the eof is a function so you must write it as

```
infile.eof()
```

or you can put the getline into while condition

```
while( getline(infile,STRING))
```